# Is there any way in which I can sort every pair of columns with the same name in a df on Python? Pandas related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting

Let's say I have the following `df`:

```
       0       1     2      3       4     5       0                1        2         3     4        5
0  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None     None
1  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None    Arena
2  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None   Marron
3  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None  Purpura
4  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None    Verde
```

How can I make the columns with the same name get sorted like this?

```
       0      0      1               1    2       2     3        3      4    4    5     5         
0  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas None            
1  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Arena     
2  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Marron    
3  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Purpura    
4  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Verde
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `axis=1`:

```
In [460]: res.sort_index(1, inplace=True)

In [461]: res
Out[461]: 
       0       0       1                1     2        2      3         3       4     4     5        5
0  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas     None
1  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas    Arena
2  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas   Marron
3  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas  Purpura
4  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas    Verde
```

Comment: Bless you sir, thank you again! 